# jQuery selector working fine when using .change(), but not fine when using .live('change')

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've got a weird issue where my code;

```
$('input[name=attachment\\[\\]').change(function(e) {
    alert("test");
});
```

Works fine, it'll alert "test", but this only works for the first of my input fields, I have a  [add more attachments] button which adds extra input fields after the page load, so I can't use .change() for that, I need to use .live('change', func.... instead.

When I use this code;

```
$('input[name=attachment\\[\\]').live('change', function(e) {
alert("test");
});
```

It no longer works, I get this syntax error;

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: input[name=attachment\[\]
```

Thanks for any help. :)

Comment: You know `live()` is deprecated as of jQuery 1.7, and removed as of 1.9? Have you tried using [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/)?

Comment: In what version of jQuery? live() has been removed in later versions !

Comment: which version of jQuery are you using? .live() is removed now. Use .on() instead

Comment: This shouldn't really work with change either.  You're missing a `]` at the end of your selector.  What version of jquery are you using?  `live` shouldn't be used unless you are pre-1.7

Comment: Ah, thanks guys. I knew it was deprecated, but didn't know it was removed, I'm using > 1.9.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expression is wrong.  You are missing the closing brace for the attribute selector.

```
$('input[name=attachment\\[\\]]')
```

You could also use

```
$('input[name="attachment[]"]')
//or
$('input[name^=attachment]')
```

Instead of `.live` you should probably use `.on`, as in:

```
$(document).on("change", "input[name^=attachment]", function () {
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have dynamic elements that you want to attach handlers to, you need to use the `on()` delegate on a parent element:

```
$(document).on('change','input[name=attachment\\[\\]',function(e) {
    alert("test");
});
```

PS: I am still confused about the `\\`, but this should at least get you in the right direction.

Comment: About the `\\\`: http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-select-an-element-by-an-id-that-has-characters-used-in-css-notation/

Comment: @Sebastien - ha, thanks a lot... learned something new today. :)

Comment: Thanks, that works. As Explosion Pills suggests, my example had a syntax error, but the new "on" thing works great, although that syntax looks a little odd to me, I'm used to selecting, then binding to an action, then running a function, this looks strange but i'll look into the changes in 1.9. :)

Comment: It still does the same thing you are used to... but now you are 1) selecting the `document` and 2) bind a `change` handler to it and 4) run a function.  The new thing is 3) where this handler only listen to `change` events that originate from an element with a specific selector (i.e. `input[name=attachment\\[\\]]`)